# Running bash script on server through ssh, unable to call Rails commands through script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bash, ssh

I have a script that commits my code to GitHub and I modified it to also run a script on the web server that is supposed to pull the new code, which it does successfully, but then is unable to run the necessary Rails commands like Rake or Bundle. I'm confused because I change to the project directory at the top of the script and `git pull` runs fine. I even tried putting the Rails command calls inside a subshell with `cd /home/rails/` at the top but that still didn't work and neither did specifying the full path to each Rails script. Am I going about this the wrong way or is there a better way to automate these two processes?

Commit script:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "$1"
git push
ssh root@example.com sh /home/rails/update_script.sh
```

Update script on server:

```
service unicorn stop
cd /home/rails/
git pull
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
bundle install
service unicorn start
exit
```

Edit: Oops, forgot the output. Here is the output from the server:

```
 * Stopping Unicorn web server unicorn
   ...done.
From https://github.com/my_name/example
   7e0fee4..17fd564  master     -> origin/master
Updating 7e0fee4..17fd564
Fast-forward
 fresh.sh | 6 +++---
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby * Starting Unicorn web server unicorn
: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
   ...done.
```

Comment: What specifically happens when your commit script tries to run the update script? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to post output. It is now located above.

Comment: It looks like the big problem is that ruby isn't in your command path on the server. What directory is the ruby executable in, and how is that directory normally added to the command path?

Comment: I'm using RVM so the output for `which ruby` is `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby`. Ruby and Rails are both working fine when I visit the website or when I log onto the server manually, I can run IRB, the Rails console, rake, bundler, all through SSH, with working aliases for just about everything. Everything works fine aside from these rake and bundler commands inside this script.

Comment: Okay, how is `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin` normally added to root's command path? I'm guessing it's in root's .bash_profile?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I did find this at the top of .bash_profile: `[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`. Do you think I can just call 'source .bash_profile' at the top of my update script? I'm confused though, why would a script, inside the same directory where all these commands already work, not have access to them? Is the update scripts scope not that from where it exists or is it instead from where its called?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to add `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin` to `$PATH`.

And I think you should run `bundle install` before running rake tasks.

Try this:

```
service unicorn stop
cd /home/rails/
git pull
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin
bundle install
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
service unicorn start
exit
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this:

`rake aborted!
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources
/home/rails/config/boot.rb:4:in <top (required)>'
/home/rails/config/application.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
/home/rails/Rakefile:4:in <top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
/home/rails/fresh.sh: 15: /home/rails/fresh.sh: bundle: not found`

Which doesn't make sense as I already have these gems installed in the very same directory that this script is saved.